# The POM for [groupId]:domain:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, maven, java-module, module-info

I am trying to build my module usecases with dependensy to my another module domain.

[this is how project structure look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m41CK.png)

domain's pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.darkyver.schedule</groupId>
<artifactId>domain</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Domain</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

usecases's pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>


<artifactId>Usecases</artifactId>
<groupId>com.darkyver.shcedule</groupId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Use Cases</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.darkyver.schedule</groupId>
        <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

So, why do i get this problem when i tried "mvn package"?

```
The POM for com.darkyver.schedule:domain:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

Comment: If these are modules of a multi-module project, you need to build from the top directory, not inside the directory of `usecases`

Comment: @JFabianMeier that is, I have to create a project that will contain all these modules?

Comment: If they are separate projects, you need to build `domain` first (with e.g. `mvn clean install`) to use it in `usecases`.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a conclusion: using java modules with maven simultaniously is bad idea. So, i deleted every module-info.java files from every modules, builded every module separatly using maven. And problem has gone